# Amazon storage unlimited bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Hi is there any version of amazon web services provides unlimited buckets?

Comment: Why do you want unlimited buckets?

Comment: not unlimited exactly lets say i will create bucket each my user ? 20-30 k

Comment: You shouldn't want to create a bucket for each user.

Comment: but i want :/ ? is it impossible , it was possible for google cloud storage but for they don't accept vcc as payment method my account gets banned :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. From the [S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html):

> Each AWS account can own up to 100 buckets at a time.

S3 buckets are expensive (in terms of resources) to create and destroy:

> The high availability engineering of Amazon S3 is focused on get, put, list, and delete operations. Because bucket operations work against a centralized, global resource space, it is not appropriate to make bucket create or delete calls on the high availability code path of your application. It is better to create or delete buckets in a separate initialization or setup routine that you run less often.

There's also no good reason to use lots of buckets:

> There is no limit to the number of objects that can be stored in a bucket and no variation in performance whether you use many buckets or just a few. You can store all of your objects in a single bucket, or you can organize them across several buckets.

You want a separate space for each of your users to put things. Fine: create a single bucket and give your user-specific information a `<user_id>/` prefix. Better yet, put it in `users/<user_id>/`, so you can use the same bucket for other non-user-specific things later, or change naming schemes, or anything else you might want.

`ListObjects` accepts a `prefix` parameter (`users/<user_id>/`), and has [special provisions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html) for hierarchical keys that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Will is correct. For cases where you can really prove a decent use-case, I'm would imagine that AWS would consider bumping your quota (as they will do for most any service). I wouldn't be surprised if particular users have 200-300 buckets or more, but not without justifying it on good grounds to AWS.

With that said, I cannot find any S3 Quota Increase form alongside the other quota increase forms.