# Dynamically create a S3 Bucket using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Aws S3 Storage for the file storages in my application ( Django ). I am using Django-Storages from Boto.

I have been reading on the S3 Storage's from http://martinbrochhaus.com/s3.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html.

My Application will have more than 1 buckets. Its like a service that allows each client to own a particular amount of storage and I am handling the storage constraint by checking the bucket size before each uploads.

I know there are ways to specify a bucket name and push the files accordingly. My Question is can we create a bucket in s3 dynamically ? ( Like when the user is approved ).

If there is a way to achieve the dynamic creation of s3buckets using Boto package in Django, kindly point me in the right direction.
Thanks !!

Comment: Use `boto`. Take a look at  http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html

Comment: as mskimm munetioned, `boto` provides python interface to s3

Comment: There are some issues with your approach that should cause you to reconsider your plan.  Bucket creation is not real time and not intended to be performed as such, [as discussed in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13593605/1695906); also, iterating to discover size will not scale, and the number of buckets you can have is limited.  Consider logical "sub"-buckets, instead.

Comment: Michael-sqlbot: Firstly thanks !! I get that using induvidual buckets is not a best-approach. But the thing is my application is going to have a single code base that is to going to be used by many clients. I dont want one client( who inturn has a number of users under him) to access another client's resources. So i was thinking to setup bucket policies to each buckets individually so that only a specific buckets can be accessed by each client. Kindly let me know if there is an alternate approach. If there is way to achieve the same with logical sub-buckets let me know. Thanks in advance.